# Count occurrences in DataFrame across columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this:

```
     Actor1 Actor2 Actor3
 0   Bob    Alice  Tom
 1   Frank  Bob    Sam
```

I want to count the number of times each actor occurs anywhere. In other words, Bob = 2, while the others are 1.

I know how to count per column and add, and I know I can merge each column into a very long Series. But there must be a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.unique` and set `return_counts=True`. This will return two lists with the unique values and counts.

```
np.unique(df, return_counts=True)
```

Output:

```
(array(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Frank', 'Sam', 'Tom'], dtype=object),
 array([1, 2, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Otherwise  you can use `df.stack().value_counts()` to which you (and @ShubhamSharma!) allude.

Comment: Otherwise you can use `df.stack().value_counts()` ;-)